# Marionette modules and RequireJS modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, marionette

I read a few posts here, and on the web in general. People don't recommend using both in the same project. However what I'm trying to get out of require with my marionette application is not having multiple script tags on the html page, and not worrying about the order js files are loaded. Can marionette accomplish this ? Please, I'd be grateful if someone could also recommend few articles on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend using Marionette and RequireJS. If you can use Require with backbone, you can use it with Marionette as well. 
Since Marionette doesn't have a script loader by default it's wise to have one. In my current project I have over 20 JS files and not having a script load would turn my project into a huge mess.

What you should consider is the scope of your application. If it's likely that it will grow beyond 500 lines of code, consider a script loader.

It's in the official docs:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs